# Script for creating development environment folder structure?

Tags: scripting, project-management, project-planning

How would look like a simple script ( cmd.exe batch, *nix shell , perl , python or whatever .. ) for creating folder structure for development environment.

Suppose we are in a project where we need more than 10 developers to bring in and we do want to ensure that all of them get the same libs and environment to ensure that "we are on the same wavelength" ...

Edit: Thanks to [randog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110177/raindog-2) ... Even if using version control system (e.g. what would be folder structure to store in the repository first ...

I mean something like:

```
::THIS BATCH FILE CREATES THE DEV ENVIRONMENT FOLDER STRUCTURE 
::CREATE THE COMMON LIBRARY FOLDER
MKDIR D:\libs\
:: FOLDER FOR LOGGING PLATFORMS - put log4net , etc here
MKDIR D:\libs\log
:: FOLDER FOR Object Relational Mapping libs
MKDIR D:\libs\orm
:: FOLDER FOR GUI 
MKDIR d:\libs\gui
:: folder for gui controls 
mkdir d:\libs\gui\controls

:: ... OTHER ?!

::CREATE THE DEVELOPER'S OWN LIBRARY FOLDER '
MKDIR D:\mylibs\
:: FOLDER FOR LOGGING PLATFORMS - put log4net , etc here
MKDIR D:\mylibs\log
:: FOLDER FOR Object Relational Mapping mylibs
MKDIR D:\mylibs\orm
:: FOLDER FOR GUI 
MKDIR d:\mylibs\gui
:: folder for gui controls 
mkdir d:\mylibs\gui\controls
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). When your developers check out the code from repository, the needed directory structure will be created automatically.

Comment: ; ) Yes !!! I should  rephrase the question ..., but what would be the first one to put in the Version Control System

Comment: The directory structure is really project-specific. I don't think there are any general recipes; it fully depends on the nature of your application. You may work on
(1) stand-alone windows program (2) web-service or (3) firmware for a digital camera or something else. These projects are really different, involve different development practices, and  will be structured differently. Also, it's a matter of taste, so I would discus this question with your developers, to make sure they feel comfortable with the structure. Sorry, nothing more specific :)

Answer (score 0):

About development environment, I would create the whole directory structure filled with relevant files in a tar/zip file. Each developer only has to extract everything from this archive for installing its environment.

About code itself, a remote repository from which each developer can checkout is best.

Comment: I have to disagree about the zip file. Everything should be checked in into version control. Loose files lying around are a no-no.

Comment: This would be the same with an installation script. Anyway you can put the zip file somewhere in the repository.